# AngularJS: IE throws 404 errors for items stored in templateCache

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am attempting to use the Angular UI Bootstrap library and IE throws a 404 error when it tries to load the typeahead-popup.html template, which is the only one I'm using right now. I am using the ui-bootstrap-tpls.0.11.0.js library, which has the templates included. The code works fine in other browsers but after inspecting the network tab, it seems that IE is trying to load the template from /app/template/typeahead/typeahead-popup.html. If I put the physical file in that location on the server, it works.

The templates failing to load are not limited to the ui-bootstrap library either. My custom library which I define using ... also does not load in IE, unless I put the physical file on the server in the /app/search.html directory.

At this point I can't figure out what the difference is between IE and the other browsers. The only thing which seems odd to me is that IE is looking in the /app directory for templates, but I wasn't sure if that was a angular thing to store the template-cached items there. Also it looks like Chrome and FF don't make a request for the template item at all, which makes sense because it should be stored only in the template cache.

I've tested in both IE10 and IE11 and it fails in both browsers, however chrome, safari, and ff all work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this was because my app was not stored at the root, and the template items in angular bootstrap ui were referenced with a relative path. I added a preceeding / and that works.